# combineLatest but for only one emission

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I'm working on an angular project and using the latest version of ngrx. I have an effect where I want to combine several observables like the below:

```js
loadSavedReplies = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(SavedRepliesActions.SavedRepliesRequested),
  mergeMap(action => combineLatest( of (action),
    this.store.pipe(select(currentUser), filter(u => u != null))
  )),
  map((s) => SavedRepliesActions.SavedRepliesLoaded({
    SaveReplies: s.model,
    a: action.id
  }))
));
```

My problem is wheneven the current user changes, and the `CombineLatest` keeps emitting. What I want is just to get one emission from the `combineLatest()`. I could only simply add `take(1)` in the `store.pipe` so `select(currentUser)` won't fire the combineLatest again, but is this the right approach. Would I need to add a `take(1)` whenever im using `combineLatest` in the effects, when i only want to get one emission.

Comment: I don't see what is wrong with using `take` operator. If you need just one value then use it. Or use `first` if you want to make additional work there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could use `combineLatest` but I think the [zip](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/zip) operator, is the best option for you (anyway you'll need extra `take` operator)

```
loadSavedReplies = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(SavedRepliesActions.SavedRepliesRequested),
  mergeMap((action)=>zip(of(action), this.store.pipe(select(currentUser),filter(...))).pipe(take(1)),
  map(([action,model]) => SavedRepliesActions.SavedRepliesLoaded({
    SaveReplies: s.model,
    a: action.id
  }))
));
```

zip will emit after both of observable emissions, and the complete using take operator

Comment: yea i thought about that, problem is withLatestFrom does not wait on the observable to emit a value. For example, in my case the selectCurrentUser does not emit a value immediately, instead it emits after it returns something other than null, and by then the source observable (action)  is not emitting anything, so i end up getting no emissions.